# mongoose how to save multiple collections in single route

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I want to save multiple collections in single express route. I am using below code in my express route file.

```
const userinfo = require('../models/userinfo');
const userdtls = require('../models/userdtls');

router.post('/add', function(req, res) {
  mongoose.connect(config.DB,{ useNewUrlParser: true }, function (err) { 
    if (err) throw err;     
    let newuserdtls = new userdtls({
      userid: '1001',
      username: req.body.username      
    })  
    newuserdtls.save()
      .then(result => {
           res.json(result);         
           console.log('successfully inserted');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.json(err)
        console.log('inserted failed',err);
      })      
    let newuserinfo = new userinfo({
      userid: '1001',
      username: req.body.username,
      gender: req.body.gender,
      class: req.body.class,
      status: req.body.status   
    })
    newuserinfo.save()
      .then(result => {
           res.json(result);          
           console.log('successfully inserted');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.json(err)
        console.log('inserted failed',err);
      })      
  })
})
```

I want to insert into these two models as single transaction. Both should be inserted successfully. If one fails other also should fail. I am also getting **"ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client"** using this code but that may be because of res.send twice. Please let me know how to combine two saves & response into one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the second record in `then` block of first record.

Or there is a better way to do this using `async/await` and `try/catch`:

```
router.post('/add', async function(req, res) {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.DB,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
    let newuserdtls = new userdtls({
      userid: '1001',
      username: req.body.username      
    })  
    await newuserdtls.save();  
    let newuserinfo = new userinfo({
      userid: '1001',
      username: req.body.username,
      gender: req.body.gender,
      class: req.body.class,
      status: req.body.status   
    })
    await newuserinfo.save();
    res.json(YOUR_RESULT);   
  } catch(err) {
    // Handle error here
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried suggested solution but it throws error.  await mongoose.connect(config.DB,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
    ^^^^^ SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

Comment: Did you try adding async before `function (req, res)`?

Comment: My Mistake. I  forgot to put async before function. Thanks a lot. It is working now.